# Unable to scroll MapView inside Stack with ListView ( Flutter )

Tags: flutter

I have this Flutter app, and i'm unable to scroll a MapView when it's inside a Stack with a ListView.

See example below:

```
    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment(0, -1),
          child: ListView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.blue,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `shrinkWrap: true` to `ListView`.